# Phase shifted Optical Fiber Bragg grating Response

Tags: optics, fiber-optics, optical-materials, photonics, braggs-law

As we know there is a narrow notch in the reflectance spectrum of a Phase shifted FBG. We have Bragg condition for reflected band of any uniform FBG. My question is that, does anyone know any relation to calculate the wavelength of narrowband in the PSFBG Spectrum ?[image]

What I mean is calculating the Wavelength 1550 in the middle of reflection spectrum.
I want to simulate this using Python and T-Matrix method. Any software suggestion to simulate PSFBG is appreciated as well.
Thanks anyone

Answer (score 1):

If you are about to calculate the lambda shift you can use bragg condition for central wavelength of a PSFBG